# android : Create Custom ListView for Each Tab

Tags: android, listview, tabview

I have Really hard time to understand that how to create different  custom listview  for each Tab of my TabView.. and is it possible to do this in single Activity.
 so, if anyone know how to implement   or tutorial for this...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

in these case you can create a custom adapter http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/ or http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=327